# Rooting nexus 7 from AOSP

Tags: rooting, vanilla-android

I have a nexus 7 flo tablet (with android 5.0.1) and I tried rooting it using twrp. It gave errors such as "can't mount /data" etc . I had to reflash from the source flo image to restore the device. 
So, I want to root the device by building the AOSP source. If i just build from source and flash the device will it give root access ? How do i proceed ?. Alternatively, if i just modify the kernel a bit and then load it, will it give me root access ?

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to find a suitable tutorial online outlining the steps required for your particular version of the nexus 7 - "grouper" (2012) vs "flo" (2013). Rooting is so much easier these days(unlike the days of odin) that it shouldn't take long for you to find a suitable guide for rooting. Also make sure to include "xda" in your search queries, as those guys are usually up to date on the best way to root your device

Comment: Try [Wugfresh NRT](http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/)

Answer (score 0):

Download Wugfresh Nexus Root Toolkit http://www.wugfresh.com/nexus-root-toolkit-2-0-5-is-out-now-with-proxy-support/

It's one of the very best methods. Additionally, the toolkit allows you to modify and flash data with a great degree of flexibility. You are going to love it.

Comment: Please mention the usage of that software to achieve the objective, in detail?